# Executing an HTTP POST request on Groovy

Tags: json, post, groovy

So I got the short straw at work and I have to learn some Groovy. I'm part of the infrastructure team, so I don't know a lot.

Basically what I have to do is:
- Get an event (DONE)
- Parse the event with an specific json format (WORKING ON IT)
- Make a POST request against the API (NOT DONE AT ALL)

So, I'm having some problems to test the POST request I'm making.
This is my code:

```
//def post = new URL("https://httpbin.org/post").openConnection();
//def message = '{"message":"this is a message"}'
def post = new URL("https://api.duckduckgo.com").openConnection();
def message = '{"q=DuckDuckGo&format=json&pretty=1"}'
post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
println(postRC);
if(postRC.equals(200)) {
    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

This is the response, the first test is from httpbin.org, the second test is from duckduckgo:

```
root@test:/mnt/c/groovy-dev/test# groovy post.groovy
200
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"message\":\"this is a message\"}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2",
    "Content-Length": "31",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Java/1.8.0_221"
  },
  "json": {
    "message": "this is a message"
  },
  "origin": "190.188.58.175, 190.188.58.175",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

root@test:/mnt/c/groovy-dev/test# groovy post.groovy
500
```

I got a response from httpbin, but not from duckduckgo. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or there is a problem with the API. Although I tested it with Postman and its working correctly.

What I'm missing?
Also, the API I will have to access in the end, uses authentication. Do you have any suggestion how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: As you can see from your tests, not all APIs work the same: your httpbin test is working, ddg test isn't because ddg doesn't even support POST method.  I'd suggest you start testing against the API that you're actually going to use.

Comment: Well, that API has authentication, its behind a proxy and I just started learning Groovy. I want to go step by step.